# trying to dynamically insert photos into horizontalscrollview (android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to extract photos from my drawable folder into an ImageView array and add the views from the array as childs to the linearlayout which is part of the horizontalscrollview.

However when I launch the app, it stops unexpectedly. Would anyone know if there is any problem with my code. Thanks a mil for your help.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class NewGallery extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_gallery);



    LinearLayout gallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);

    Field[] field = R.drawable.class.getFields();

    final int arraylength = field.length;









        ImageView[] images = new ImageView[arraylength];

        for (int i=0; i<=arraylength; i=i+1)
                { 


                  images[i] = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());           
                  images[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("icon"+i, "drawable", getPackageName())));
                  gallery.addView(images[i]);

                }





}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_new_gallery, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: please post you logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, refer to logcat error messages. I think you got a ClassCastException due to incorrect casting :

```
LinearLayout gallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mygallery).
```

Are you sure you are casting the correct view ?